# Manually convert XML SOAP response into PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, soap

I'm trying to convert XML SOAP response into PHP array, here is XML SOAP response:

```
string(1182) "<AuctionList IsValid="True" TotalRecords="90">
                <Auction ID="112906125" Name="SOFTWARESYSTEMS.CO" Traffic="0" BidCount="0" Price="$11 USD" ValuationPrice="-" TimeLeft="17M 9S" RowID="1"/>
                <Auction ID="112557715" Name="SOFTWAREINTEC.INFO" Traffic="0" BidCount="0" Price="$8 USD" ValuationPrice="-" TimeLeft="18M 9S" RowID="2"/>
                <Auction ID="101835614" Name="SOFTWARERULETA.COM" Traffic="20" BidCount="0" Price="$25 USD" ValuationPrice="-" TimeLeft="24M 9S" RowID="3"/>
                <Auction ID="112573759" Name="SOFTWAREINTEC.COM" Traffic="2" BidCount="0" Price="$5 USD" ValuationPrice="-" TimeLeft="28M 9S" RowID="4"/>
                <Auction ID="112648957" Name="SOFTWAREASSETMANAGEMENTJOBS.COM" Traffic="7" BidCount="0" Price="$8 USD" ValuationPrice="-" TimeLeft="41M 9S" RowID="5"/>
            </AuctionList>"
```

This response is result of Godaddy auction API for domain details.

I have tried it to parse it into string but getting errors:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): namespace warning : xmlns: URI GdAuctionsBiddingWSAPI is not absolute in C:\xampp\htdocs\adam_auction\index.php on line 94

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): w.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><GetAuctionList2Response xmlns="GdAuctionsBiddingWSAPI" in C:\xampp\htdocs\adam_auction\index.php on line 94

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\adam_auction\index.php on line 94
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) { ["GetAuctionList2Response"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) { ["GetAuctionList2Result"]=> string(768) "" } }
```

Any help how to convert that response into PHP array?

Comment: Have you consider using SoapClient to interact with the API? It will return the response as an array/object.http://php.net/soapclient

Comment: Also, this same string when loaded with simplexml_load_string works just fine here. The error appears to be on another part of the text.

Comment: @Hisamu, I didn't yet consider SoapClient, I'm using CURL. And if you parse that string, it returns valid array but in fact the response is SOAP XML response and which is not easy to parse.

Comment: Could you post the entire response in a pastebin so I can test here?

Comment: @Hisamu, Here is my entire response: http://pastebin.com/9wzUV8Pw. Please help how to convert it into array.

Comment: @Hisamu, I posted the entire code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229478/soap-request-using-soapclient

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_string(your xml response);

$Auction = $xml->Auction;
foreach($Auction as $Auc)
{
$short_name[] =  $Auc['Name'];  
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($short_name);
 ?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => SOFTWARESYSTEMS.CO
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => SOFTWAREINTEC.INFO
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => SOFTWARERULETA.COM
        )

    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => SOFTWAREINTEC.COM
        )

    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => SOFTWAREASSETMANAGEMENTJOBS.COM
        )

)
```

Comment: Getting error with your code:'Warning: simplexml_load_string(): namespace warning : xmlns: URI GdAuctionsBiddingWSAPI is not absolute in '...there are others too.

Comment: Show your actual response from soap

Comment: When I use firefox client, the response is pastebin.com/9wzUV8Pw but when I use var_dump then response is, see code in my question